# Capture Templated Argument with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I wish to do the following:

```
when(response.readEntity(entityTypeCaptor)).thenReturn(100);
```

where `readEntity` is:

```
public abstract <T> T readEntity(Class<T> entityType);
```

and where the code I am testing is as follows:

```
 int number = response.readEntity(Integer.class);
```

What type should I declare entityTypeCaptor with?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this approach :

`when(response.readEntity(any())).thenReturn(100);`

If you won't check exact type (or you don't know exact type) of `entityTypeCaptor` otherwise you can do this :

`when(response.readEntity(eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(100);`

And check exact type, in this case `Class<Integer>`.

Here is example of code :

```
@Test   
public void test() {
    //Given
    Response response = Mockito.mock(Response.class);

    //THEN
    when(response.readEntity(eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(100);

    //WHEN
    Integer result = response.readEntity(Integer.class);

    assertEquals(100, result.intValue());
  }

class Response {

    public <T> T readEntity(Class<T> entityType){
        return null;
    }
}
```